# php explode - split array into rows

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, split, explode

I have a widget that has 3 columns **Name** / **Occupation** / **Reg** users can add as many people as the want.

But the data comes through like this:

Array ( [0] => [{"Name":"Bob [1] => Smith","Occupation":"Administrator","Registration":"1234"},{"Name":"James [2] => Richards","Occupation":"Technician","Registration":"4345353"}] )

**PHP code used**:

```
$people=$_POST['q36_addIndividuals'];
$str = $people;
print_r (explode(' ',$str));
```

**What I want is it to look like this instead:**

Bob Smith - Administrator - 1234
James Richards - Technician - 4345353

Comment: Please post your entire code so we can help you further. For example we do not know what the value of `$_POST['q36_addIndividuals']` looks like

Comment: this is the widget used [link]https://form.jotform.com/60255263620953 that is submitted to my php file which only contains the following php `code` $people=$_POST['q36_addIndividuals'];
$str = $people;
print_r (explode(' ',$str));

Comment: Could you do a `print_r($_POST);` and post the results in your question please

Comment: print_r($_POST); gives the following result:


[{"Name":"Bob smith","Occupation":"ADMIN","Registration":"12233"},{"Name":"James Richards","Occupation":"Tech","Registration":"43453543"}]

Comment: Post the whole array

Comment: that is the whole array...my php only contains the following code <?php  print_r($_POST['q36_addIndividuals']);  ?>

Comment: `print_r($_POST);` not `print_r($_POST['q36_addIndividuals']);`

Comment: Array ( [submission_id] => 329640190094197435 [formID] => 60255263620953 [ip] => 80.5.254.90 [clickto] => [{"Name":"Bob","Occupation":"admin","Registration":"123"}] )

I've added a submit button if you want to give it a try: https://form.jotform.com/60255263620953

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have some JSON Data, but it is not correct.

Correct Version would be:

```
$data = '[{"Name":"Bob [1] => Smith","Occupation":"Administrator","Registration":"1234"},{"Name":"James [2] => Richards","Occupation":"Technician","Registration":"4345353"}]';

$data = json_decode($data);

foreach ($data as $json) {

    echo $json->Name . ' - ' . $json->Occupation . ' - ' . $json->Registration;
    echo "\n";
}
```

This will output something like this:

```
Bob [1] => Smith - Administrator - 1234  
James [2] => Richards - Technician - 4345353
```

But you should consider storing the Firstname and the Lastname in two different values, sou you can access them.

You can also "remove" the `[n] =>`, but this is the dirty way. I don't recommend this!

```
$data = '[{"Name":"Bob [1] => Smith","Occupation":"Administrator","Registration":"1234"},{"Name":"James [2] => Richards","Occupation":"Technician","Registration":"4345353"}]';

$data = json_decode($data);

foreach ($data as $json) {

    $json->Name = preg_replace(['/[[(0-9)]]|[=>]|[[]|/', '/   /'], ['', ' '], $json->Name);
    echo $json->Name . ' - ' . $json->Occupation . ' - ' . $json->Registration; // not recommended
    echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: This did the job! I cant thank you enough! many thanks for taking the time to help me! and to all the others also!!!!

Answer (score 1):

the print_r function only pastes the structure of the array.

if you want a different form, you need to iterate through the array and write it out for each element:

```
 foreach($people as $element){
  echo $element['Name']." - ".
  $element['Occupation']." - ".
  $element['Registration'];  
 }
```

Comment: I was getting there and know exactly what print_r does

Comment: Its coming through as blank am i missing something?

<?php 

$people=$_POST['q36_addIndividuals'];

 foreach($people as $element){
  echo $element['Name']." - ".
  $element['Occupation']." - ".
  $element['Registration']." - ";  
 }



?>

Comment: sorry, could you put the following and post the output so i know what one element of the array is?:
                foreach($people as $element){
                    print_r("next_element");
                    print_r($element);
                    echo "</br>";
                }